Configure a Website so that It Serves its Pages from a Subfolder
I am trying to configure a website so that it serves its pages from a subfolder.
The website's root folder is the following.
/home/infcs/server/public/apps/mysite

The website's root folder contains an .htaccess that points to the following subfolder that contains the actual website files.
/home/infcs/server/public/apps/mysite/public

The .htaccess file's content is the following.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

When I try to load the page http://localhost/apps/mysite, I get the error message:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

My apache sites-available config file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf looks like follows.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/infcs/server/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

I also have this in my apache config file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.
<Directory /home/infcs/server/public/apps/mysite>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

I have tried changing .htaccess to the following:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps/mysite/public/    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /apps/mysite/public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Now I can see the page but it fails to load the assets e.g. css, js, etc. For example, I see the following in the console:
GET
http://localhost/store/1/default_images/categories_icons/feather.png
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
GET
http://localhost/assets/default/js/app.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

The store folder is this one:
/home/infcs/server/public/apps/mysite/public/store

The assets folder is this one:
/home/infcs/server/public/apps/mysite/public/assets

I do not know much about .htaccess files, so I tried to hack the .htaccess file by looking at another .htaccess file with which I had some luck, but as you can see, it does not work.
Could you please show me how I can solve this?
Many thanks.

Why not just point the webroot to the public folder instead of jumping through htaccess hoops?

@Eric, do you mean I change the line "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/" to "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/(.*)"?

@aynber, I have other apps on the server, so I cannot make the document root point specifically to this website.

Just because you have multiple apps on the server doesn't mean you can't point them directly to the webroot, unless you don't have them separated out by domains. I have several websites on one server, all with their own conf files and webroots
